# React Native release fails to start

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React Native release build fails to start. Below is the logcat message

> ReactNativeJS: Can't find variable: runInContext
>
> 03-09 18:45:53.178 20609 20633 E ReactNativeJS: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
>
> 03-09 18:45:53.195 20609 20634 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
>
> 03-09 18:45:53.195 20609 20634 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myapp, PID: 20609
>
> 03-09 18:45:53.195 20609 20634 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Can't find variable: runInContext, stack:

There are few other errors like

> 03-09 18:45:52.618 20609 20621 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager
> 03-09 18:45:52.622 20609 20621 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.viewpager.ReactViewPagerManager
> 03-09 18:45:52.625 20609 20621 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextViewManager

The debug version runs properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading to `uglify-js@2.8.9`.

Full details here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12772