# React Native Release - Can't find variable: runInContext

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm working on a react native app and having an issue when I switch the iOS build to release and try to run on device. I see the default built with react native loading screen but then it just white screens Everything runs fine while scheme is set to Debug.

Xcode console shows the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException:
Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: runInContext'
```

The error is thrown from RCTBatchedBridge.m but the call stack it gives me doesn't give much information

```
<unknown>@476:4171
<unknown>@476:7841
<unknown>@476:7999
n@2:545
<unknown>@470:540
n@2:545
<unknown>@455:382
n@2:545
<unknown>@368:162
n@2:545
<unknown>@12:86
n@2:545
i@2:266
global code@715:9
```

I did do a grep through the project to see where the variable is defined, which returned a lot of lodash files. I can't figure out though why it works fine in debug compared to release.

I'm not really sure where to go from here to figure out what is going on and searching around I haven't found any answers.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I found the answer. [React Native release fails to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696564/react-native-release-fails-to-start)

Issue is caused by uglify js. Installing the newest version will fix the build.

```
npm i --save uglify-js@2.8.22
```